# How to use another page before App.js in react js

Tags: reactjs

How can we use another page before App.js
I use the following code but output screen area showing blank

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "App";
import Sign from "./layouts/authentication/sign-in/index";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button"; 

// Soft UI Dashboard React Context Provider
import { SoftUIControllerProvider } from "context";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <SoftUIControllerProvider>
      <Sign />
       
      
    </SoftUIControllerProvider>

  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: Think you want to do something like this [Add login authenication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-login-authentication-to-react-applications)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing your route declarations, To declare your app routing, You should have 2 common options:

1. You should wrap your app screens with [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes#routes), and [`Route`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#route) components:

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
... your component imports ...

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Sign />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

2. Use [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-routes) hook to define your routes with an array of route objects:

```
const App = () => {
  let element = useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Sign />,
    }
  ]);

  return element;
}
```